# EOFException con RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, archivo, cmd

Tengo un problema con la ejecución de un proyecto en CMD. El caso es que tengo un método que me lee un fichero .dat con varias líneas escritas en bytes con un objeto de la misma clase RandomAccess y, al ejecutarlo en NetBeans, el proyecto se ejecuta sin ningún problema y me muestra lo que quiero, pero al ejecutarlo en CMD con argumentos, salta error.

```
public void accederLeer(int posicion) { 
try {
    RandomAccessFile random = new RandomAccessFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), "r");
    random.seek(posicion*20-20);
    System.out.println(random.readUTF()+" "+random.readInt()+" "+random.readFloat());


} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TareaEvaluacion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TareaEvaluacion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    TareaEvaluacion e = new TareaEvaluacion();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        
        e.accederLeer(Integer.parseInt(args[i]));
    }
      
}
```

El error que me sale el el cmd es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He hecho otras pruebas en el main sin utilizar el RandomAccess y ejecuta perfectamente.

Comment: El archivo .dat esta dentro del JAR?

Comment: @JFrame si, esta dentro del mismo proyecto, en la carpeta principal